# How do I programmatically publish a Map Service Definition to an ArcGIS Server in ArcGIS 10 or 10.1?

Tags: publish, arcgis, esri, arcgis-server, arcpy

I have an C# desktop application that needs to allow the user to specify an ArcGIS map service definition (.MSD) for publishing to a server.

How can I programmatically publish a given .MSD to an ArcGIS Server from a desktop that is connected to the server?  Any links or APIs that might help with this?  Also, I am open to C# or Python for this solution.